# Spring Expression (SpEL) - Rounding

Tags: spring-el

Is there a way to specify rounding precision when evaluating math operation using SpEL?
For example

```
ExpressionParser parser  = new SpelExpressionParser();
Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("2/3");
exp.getValue(Double.class); //returns 0.0 instead of 0.666666667
```

Or is this a limitation in SpEL?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
"2.0/3"
```

and result is `0.6666666666666666`.

Does it make sense?

The point of the `getValue(Double.class)` is eliminated here since your `2/3` is just an operation between two integers and the result is an integer as well - `0`.
And only after that this result is converted to expected double as a `0.0`.

You need to explicitly say in the expression that you are going to deal with doubles.

You may consider this as a limitation, but `getValue(Double.class)` is not a *casting* operation like in Java. It is a post-conversion. Therefore precision is just lost because your expression evaluates to integer anyway.

Comment: I see...It makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is for searchers as me - who googled "SpEL rounding precision". If you use it already in script/expression like {{car.price}} you can add .doubleValue(). So it will be {{car.price.doubleValue()}} and you can do also {{car.price.doubleValue()+conditioner.price.doubleValue()}}. It gives more precision..