# Arithmetic Operations using SPEL

Tags: java, spring-el

In our project We want to evaluate expression in the form ("122/10") and the result should come as 12.2. But the result is coming as 12 always. How to get the result of 12.2 using SPEL.Please provide your suggestions without using ScriptEngine in java.

Comment: Tried using `122.0/10`?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of [Spring Expression (SpEL) - Rounding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55293666/spring-expression-spel-rounding)

Comment: If the left and right operand is Integer SpEL is giving the Integer value. The String ("122/10") which I shared is a simple one.  What about the String having      
 ("122/10*(2*3*5)") which is dynamically created.